# Is there a way to get p,d,q,P,D,Q params from statsforecast AutoARIMA

Tags: python, time-series, forecasting, statsforecast

minimal example:

```
from statsforecast import StatsForecast
from statsforecast.models import AutoARIMA
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('https://datasets-nixtla.s3.amazonaws.com/air-passengers.csv')


sf = StatsForecast(
    models = [AutoARIMA(season_length = 12)],
    freq = 'M',
    n_jobs=-1,
    verbose=True
)

sf.fit(df)
```

How to get the parameters of the fitted model ?

I know this is possible using `pmdarima` package, but pmdarima is way too slow and runs out of memory on large data. `statsforecast` seems promising, but only if there is a way to get the params

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75290492/how-to-get-model-specification-paramters-for-models-estimated-with-nixtlas-stat), the solution would be:

```
sf.fitted_[0][0].model_['arma']
```

which will output a tuple of 7 values.  I don't know the exact mapping of parameters to tuple values, but from [this line](https://github.com/Nixtla/statsforecast/blob/main/statsforecast/arima.py#L2326) it appears to be:

```
(p, d, q, P, D, Q, constant)
```